# Data recovery from my SSD encrypted with Veracrypt is not working having the password

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, data-recovery, truecrypt, veracrypt

I have one SSD and one HDD. My SSD is encrypted with Veracrypt. Yesterday my SSD just stop to work and I can not do much from my SSD so I have installed Veracrypt on my HDD in order to get back all my data. I have the password so I expected to recover all the information without problems, but when I try to Permanently decrypt...  I get back:

Operation failed due to one or more of the following:

-Incorrect Password.

-Incorrect PIM number.

-Incorrect PRF (hash).

-Not a value volume.

Source:Mount Volume:9170

I am sure that the password is correct as I had to insert it always that I entered to my SSD.
My PIM number was an empty space so that should not be a problem neither.

What am I doing wrong a part of using Veracrypt without enough knowledge to do so?

Comment: Does the password work for accessing the encrypted data?

Comment: @harrymc - The author is attempting to decrypt the drive, when they enter the password, VeraCrypt indicates the password (or some other parameter) was incorrect.

Comment: M_1, you should update your question with additional information what type of encryption you used. Did you use Veracrypt to encrypt a bootable installation? Or did you encrypt just a partition? Or did you encrypt a file on your disk?

Answer (score 1):

If your password and PIM (you have none) are correct, it's probably
due to header corruption. There's a backup header embedded in each volume.
You can try restoring this backup header.

This is done from the
[Program Menu](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Program%20Menu.html)
to use
[Tools -> Restore Volume Header](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Program%20Menu.html#tools-restore-volume-header).

Read well the documentation and the warnings, especially this one:

> WARNING: Restoring a volume header also restores the volume password that was valid when the backup was created. Moreover, if keyfile(s) are/is necessary to mount a volume when the backup is created, the same keyfile(s) will be necessary to mount the volume again after the volume header is restored.

Note well that this operation is dangerous and may lose your data.
You should verify first that you have some kind of backup.

Comment: I would assume that if the author had a backup they would just use that instead of attempting to decrypt their SSD.

Comment: @Ramhound: "some kind of backup" means even one that is not totally up to date, so that not everything is lost. (When will users understand that Veracrypt is a dangerous tool that can encrypt but not always decrypt?)

Comment: As @harrymc states, make an image of the SSD **as it is now** before attempting any change that could destroy data on it. Then you can revert to the current image.

Comment: Thank you all for this information. I haven't been able to solve it yet. I had decrypt my SSD using Elcomsoft Forensic Disk, after using it I have got my SSD in a .raw image. I am not sure what I should do next. I have a backup of my data not up to date. @harrymc I agree with you, I shouldn't use veracrypt with my lack of knowledge on this field.