# Data Recovery from Veracrypt-Encrypted External Drive After Power Fluctuation

Tags: hard-drive, backup, encryption, recovery, veracrypt

I find myself in a bit of a predicament and am reaching out for guidance on recovering data from a specific partition on a 1TB external hard drive, where all partitions are encrypted with Veracrypt. This 256GB partition houses crucial files, including work documents and emails, and encountered an unexpected dismount during a recent power fluctuation.

Here's a breakdown of the situation:

I initially encrypted all partitions on a 1TB external hard drive using Veracrypt to secure all my important files. Unfortunately, a power fluctuation occurred yesterday, leading to an abrupt dismount of the Veracrypt-encrypted 256GB partition.

In an attempt to recover the data, I restarted the system and initiated a file system repair since the partition was functional up until that point. Chkdsk was run, and it took several hours to complete. However, during step 4, the process seemed to have abruptly terminated, encountering segments that were unreadable.

Now, although the 256GB partition successfully mounts, Windows recognizes the data as raw. To compound matters, I realized that, despite having a backup, the files' last modification dates were two years ago, raising concerns about the backup process.

Given the critical nature of the data, I'm uncertain about the best course of action. Should I try rerunning chkdsk with different parameters, attempt to decrypt the partition, or explore third-party recovery tools? I'm hesitant, fearing that I might inadvertently worsen the situation.

It's worth mentioning that the remaining partition on the 1TB drive functions flawlessly.

I am open to any suggestions, advice, or experiences you can share to guide me through this challenging situation. My primary goal is to exhaust every possible avenue to salvage as much data as possible.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: When was the last image made of the drive? Drives don't work forever, and surely you have made a backup image?

Comment: I have used a program called GoodScync and although it was running every few hours it obviously hasn't mirrored the files for quite some time. Using the backup is not an option.

Comment: @Moldevort - With encryption backing up is your only option in a case like you describe.

Comment: With wich program and what do to when I backed it up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data recovery from my SSD encrypted with Veracrypt is not working having the password](https://superuser.com/questions/1709836/data-recovery-from-my-ssd-encrypted-with-veracrypt-is-not-working-having-the-pas)

Comment: I am currently backing up the volume and start experimenting with different approaches - I will have a look at restoring the header. Thank you for the hint

Comment: Unfortunately, restoring the backed up header within the volume hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello SuperUser community,

I am excited to share that I have successfully recovered over 99% of my data using R-Studio. Here's a brief overview of the process:

1. Mounted the volume in VeraCrypt.
2. Scanned and visualized the partition in R-Studio. Up to
   approximately 56%, only sporadic I/O errors were encountered. At
   56%, progress halted for many hours due to a significant number of
   faulty sectors. It was crucial to set "0 additional read attempts"
   in the options at this point.
3. After the progress remained at 56% overnight, I decided to skip a
   few gigabytes and resume the scan (possible in the settings).
   Additionally, an exclusion region was defined to prevent rescanning
   and stalling of this specific section.
4. Upon completion, I used R-Studio to display all files and
   successfully restored them.